# Hassidim and their socks

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

Is there a way of differentiating between different sects of chassidim by the type and color of socks that they wear as well as by how they wear them?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Gur is easy to distinguish a length pants and socks over the pants.  The last chasiduyot many of them with short pants and white length socks ay Shabbos

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic This question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: ....as strange as this question is, it would seem to be on topic. It is about Jewish practice and minhag, which the Chassidish "Levush" certainly is. That said, @Mark, the real answer is "no". First, there are *dozens* of different Chassidic sects, so even if they all wore different socks, it would be difficult or impossible to tell them apart, unless one was a real sock "mayven". And some of them wear the same socks in the same way as others.

Comment: Mark, why do you think there might be?  Have you seen some community differences?  Did somebody say this?  Anything you can add to the question to provide context will help people in answering (and maybe in learning something new).  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkA Yeah I think the high white socks are only worn by some sects (not only Ger) and only for Shabbos/yom tov/chasuna etc. Now women's stockings, that I could tell you about in detail.

Comment: Is this really on topic? Maybe if the question was about *why* there are differences. But not sure about the current format.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot determine sect solely by the socks, but often you can tell *something* based on the socks. Combining sock style with hat/jacket/girdle/shoe/glasses/shirt style will narrow things down even further, as will observation of an individual on both weekdays, shabbos, and holidays. Together with knowledge of which sects are common locally, it is often possible to determine exact sect with high accuracy.

All the following are generalizations; each sect has individuals which differ:

- In many sects, only married men wear high black socks on weekdays.
- In Belz and related sects, even unmarried men wear that.
- Satmar and related sects often wear long pants on weekdays.
- In many sects, married men wear high white socks on shabbos and holidays.
- In Satmar, many wear long pants even on shabbos and holidays.
- In Belz and related sects, married men wear high black socks on shabbos, but white on holidays.
- In some Jerusalem-based chassidic sects (especially for sect names that begin with *Toldos*) even unmarried men wear high white socks on shabbos and holidays.
- If someone is wearing high white socks on a weekday without wearing a shtreimel (because that would indicate a personal festive day) you can safely assume them to be of a rabbinic family.
- Ger and related groups wear high black socks with normal pants which are tucked into the socks – all week.
- Other "Russian" chassidic sects (e.g. Chabad and Karlin) never wear high socks.

*Source: Living in chassidic neigborhoods for over a decade.*

---

<sup>I wear high black socks on weekdays and white ones on shabbos and holidays.</sup>